# ajax request getting redirected to /system/sling/cqform/defaultlogin.html

Tags: ajax, web-services, aem

Im making an **ajax call** from **cq** to a **webservice**, however the ajax call returns the below response

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var u="/system/sling/cqform/defaultlogin.html?resource=%2Ferror%2F500.html&$$login$$=%24%24login%24%24"; 
                if ( window.location.hash) {u = u + window.location.hash;}
                document.location = u;
            </script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <!-- QUICKSTART_HOMEPAGE - (string used for readyness detection, do not remove) -->
    </body>
</html>
```

May I know what exactly the above response means?

Note: cookies and necessary headers are set to the ajax request for making the call to the webservice.
Also this ajax call is working fine in all the other cq environments,it is having the above issue in only one environment.

Thanks,
Balaji.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link in script points to login form. So I think, that service can be accessed only by logged-in/some CUG users.

**UPD1**

To find reason, you should check permissions of your user, also Dispatcher configuration can be a problem there.

Comment: Thanks Alex, yes our certificates got expired, we renewed them,still the issue is there, do we need to restart the app and web server .

Comment: @balaji, have you checked logs, any messages there? It's really hard to say there, what should be done. I would try to restart first.

Comment: Ya correct restart helped us thanks for ur help Alex :)